# Fortran end of file error when input file is not in src folder

Tags: file, fortran

I have a small fortran program:

```
integer :: ok
real :: x
character(len=80) :: name
name="test.txt"
open(1,file=name,status='old',iostat=ok)
print *,ok
read(1,*) x
close(1)
print *,x
```

and it works for now. 
But When I do something like this (of course i put my file in this dir)

```
name="/data/test.txt"
```

or this

```
name = "../data/input.txt"
```

I get the error:

```
At line 8 of file test.f90 (unit = 1, file = 'fort.1')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

I use gfortran compiler. 
UPDATE:
Absolute path like "/Users/name/Documents/fortran/data/input.txt"  works too!

Comment: What is your current directory from where you run it?

Comment: /Users/name/Documents/fortran/src/test.f90 something like that. I have macos(it has unix filesystem)

Comment: `/data/input.txt` is an absolute path. Have you tried `data/input.txt` (note the lack of leading forward slash)? You will have to run it from `/Users/name/Documents/fortran/`.